# Term a plea "frivolous" or term a "frivolous plea"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I read an article in "The Hindu" which was titled as:

> In 2015, SC had termed ‘frivolous’ plea on Rahul’s citizenship

Now, the article [(source)](https://www.thehindu.com/elections/lok-sabha-2019/sc-had-termed-frivolous-plea-on-rahuls-citizenship/article26996174.ece?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=Newsletter) talks about a plea filed by Rahul which was described by SC as "frivolous". So, it got me into thinking that the title should be more like

> In 2015, SC had termed a plea on Rahul’s citizenship as "frivolous".

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Article headlines, often do not follow rules of grammar, that needs getting used to.

This is a sentence construct designed to be punchy, the fact that SC has called something frivolous was considered more important that was was insulted.

It is actually missing is the word 'the'

> In 2015, SC had termed ‘frivolous’ the plea on Rahul’s citizenship